# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" C# and Oracle

Tags: c#, database, oracle, dapper

I'm trying to run a SQL query in my Oracle database using C# (Dapper Library), I made some adaptations to make it work, and I had no problems with queries like update and select, however, when trying to insert, I'm getting the error

> ORA-00933 : SQL command not properly ended

Here is the query

```
insert into Car_Names (Model, Descr) 
values (:Model, :Descr);
```

[And an image with more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HLEz.png)

Originally, the library would have sent column names with braces, e.g.

```
insert into ... ([column], [column2]) ...
```

But I was getting another error so I removed that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing semi-colon is something that is used in *tools* to indicate the end of a command, eg SQLcl, SQLPlus, SQL Developer etc.

Thus, when these tools see the semi-colon, they send the SQL statement to the database *without* the semi-colon. Thus with other drivers (C#, python, node, etc etc) you compose the SQL statement without it, ie

```
insert into Car_Names (Model, Descr) 
values (:Model, :Descr)
```